# What was the significance of the subplot involving 1934 California gubernatorial election in Mank?

Tags: analysis, mank

*Mank* (2020) film discuss about film about screenwriter Herman J. Mankiewicz and his 
development of the screenplay for Citizen Kane (1941).

I didn't understand the purpose of subplot "1934 California gubernatorial election"
in this film.

[image]

Here is the movie screenshot of voting board of 1934 California gubernatorial election
at an election night watch party at the Trocadero Nightclub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Held in the midst of the Great Depression, the 1934 election was amongst the most controversial in the state's political history.<sup>1</sup>

> Negative campaigning funded by the film industry was used against Sinclair to favor the Merriam campaign.<sup>2</sup>

> In 1934, Herman and Joseph begin working at MGM under Mayer. Studio executives, including Irving Thalberg, actively work against Sinclair's gubernatorial campaign. The studio produces propaganda films for a smear campaign, funded by Hearst, against Sinclair.<sup>3</sup>

It's another important part of the animosity between Hearst and Mank. If you [remember](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/119430/53946) that "*during Upton Sinclair's race for governor of California in 1934, Mank refused the MGM chief Louis B. Mayer's order to hand over a donation to Sinclair's Republican opponent*", then the election is clearly another page of their not-so-friendly story.

---

<sup>1. 2. 3. from Wikipedia</sup>